# How to reduce voltage from a high speed buffer?

Tags: level-shifting, voltage-divider, signal-integrity

I am using [this buffer](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT245.pdf) to connect signal between 2.5 V and 5.5 V to a 3.3 V microcontroller.

The problem is I will get a 5 V output and my microcontroller doesn't have 5 V tolerant inputs so I have to reduce it to 3.3 V. The perfect solution would be [something like this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc8t245.pdf). It has double power supply, one for input voltage and the other for output voltage so level conversion is easy. But in my country (Argentina) it doesn't exists and buying it at international shops would be expensive (we have lots of taxes).

So, I have the first chip with 5 V outputs and my microcontroller needs 3.3 V. I was thinking of a simple voltage divider with resistors on each output, but the buffer is bi-directional and that will decrease the input voltage to the input.

So I thought of using 1N4148 diodes connected to a power supply of 3.3 V - Vdiode in order to activate the diode if the voltage exceeds 3.3 V. I need a resistor to limit the current in that case? I have clock signals of about 35 MHz, would that affect my signal?

Comment: Where did you get that chip then?

Comment: I get the first chip, not the second one whit double power supply

Comment: I meant: where did you get the first chip?

Comment: Here http://www.electrocomponentes.com/, it sells that chip. Or here http://www.elemon.com.ar/elemon/

Comment: Any reason you can't run the HCT245 from 3.3V? What's on the other side of the HCT245? What exactly do you mean by "between 2.5V and 5.5V" - is that the signal HI/LO, or the variance of the signal HI (e.g. 0-2.5V to 0-5.5V)

Comment: If I power it from 3.3V I won't be able to put 5V signals on input (we are always talking about digital signals '1' and '0') and I am not sure if it we able to handle 40MHz frequency because at 2V the propagation delay from input to output is tipically 25nS and max 90nS and is too much if my input signal at 40MHz has a 25nS period.

Comment: Electrocomponentes seems to be a local distributor for Farnell (There's a giant Farnell ad on the page you linked), and Farnell certainly carries the 74LVC8T245. Maybe you have to call them up to find out the pricing, but you ought to be able to get the part. I've had Farnell ship goods from England to their USA branch (Newark) and they paid the international shipping...but of course I'm not sure what are their arrangements for shipping to other countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the only way I could achieve this was asking for samples of 74LVC8T245. 40MHz is considerably high frequency to easily reduce input voltage.